# Flip and zoom 3D transition problems (iOS 7+)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, core-animation, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm trying to build transition for card flip & zoom. I've made its model in Origami - [Movie (less that 1Mb)](http://cl.ly/0w2D252J3V25)

As you can see there are 3 transforms applied at the same time: 
1. moving center of the view to the centre of the screen
2. scaling
3. 3D rotte

We can divide animation on equal 2 phases:
**Phase 1:** Button scales, moves and rotates on the side (PI/2 radians). At the end of Phase 1 button disappears.
**Phase 2:** `toView` (my modal view) rotates (from -PI/2 to 0 radians), scales up to the normal size and moves view's centre to the screen centre.
If we're excluding bouncing - it is pretty straightforward transforms.

But I've met several problems while building it:
1. I'm flipping just a button, not the whole view. There is a background behind this button. So, if I apply `CATransform3DMakeRotation` half of the button disappears - it intersects with background in 3D space (Z axis). Is there a way to use 3DTransform here?
2. There are some artefacts on the screen. I don't have any idea where are they coming from.

You can check [result movie](http://cl.ly/1F320e3T203c) (3.8Mb). I've slowed down animation for the second card in the movie.

Here is my code for this animation:

```
func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

let container = transitionContext.containerView()

let fromViewBig = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)!
let toView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)!

// Converting button to UIImageView and hiding actual button
let button = sourceViewController.view.viewWithTag(sourceViewController.buttonIndex)!
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(button.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
button.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
var img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
let fromView = UIImageView(frame: button.frame)
fromView.image = img
button.hidden = true

container.addSubview(toView)
container.addSubview(fromView)



let duration = self.transitionDuration(transitionContext)

// Add a perspective transform
var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
transform.m34 = -0.002
container.layer.sublayerTransform = transform

//calculating "median" frame size - size of the frame in 1/2 of animation
let medianX = (toView.frame.width + fromView.frame.width) / 2
let medianY = (toView.frame.height + fromView.frame.height) / 2

// at the midpoint of our animation final size of fromView should be equal to starting size of toView
// initial scale transfor fo toView (it will appear in second half of animation)
let initialToScaleTransform = CATransform3DMakeScale(medianX/toView.frame.width, medianY/toView.frame.height, 1.0)
// final scale of fromView
let finalFromScaleTransform = CATransform3DMakeScale(medianX/fromView.frame.width, medianY/fromView.frame.height, 1.0)
let finalToScaleTransform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)

// our view is moving diring animation too
let startCenter = fromView.center
let endCenter = toView.center
let midCenter = CGPoint(x: (startCenter.x + endCenter.x)/2, y: (startCenter.y + endCenter.y)/2)

// flip the to VC halfway round - hiding it
toView.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(initialToScaleTransform, CGFloat(-M_PI_2), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
toView.center = midCenter

// animate
UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(duration, delay: 0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.allZeros, animations: { () -> Void in
    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.0, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
        fromView.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(finalFromScaleTransform, CGFloat(M_PI_2), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        fromView.center = midCenter
    })
    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.5, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
        toView.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(finalToScaleTransform, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        toView.center = endCenter
    })
}) { (finished) -> Void in
    transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled())
}
}
```

Comment: Regarding the depth-based clipping of half of your view as it rotates... Have you tried setting the zPosition property of your layers as a solution?

Comment: I've tried to do it recently. changing zPosition isn't a good solution because few factors: 1. I can't really find zPozition value large enough to rid off intersection. 2. Views are actually zoom in when you're increasing zPosition.

Comment: Is there any way you could manage two separate view/layer hierarchies, and apply your 3D transform to only one of them (the one on top)? I.e. instead of applying it to `container.layer`, apply it to a sublayer of it (and keep other sublayers unaffected).

Comment: Thanks. I've copied perspective transform `transform.m34 = -0.002` from an example. In my case if I don't do perspective transform I can increase zPosition even to 1000 without changing view's size.