# Create flip animation with origami

Tags: quartz-composer, origami

How to create 3d card flip animation with Facebook origami. I have tried so much and I couldn't find a way to do this any help would be really appreciated.

Please check the sample video provided on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29017038/flip-and-zoom-3d-transition-problems-ios-7)

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].